# Time complexity of set in Java

Tags: java, time-complexity

Can someone tell me the time complexity of the below code?

`a` is an array of int.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (set.contains(arr[i])) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    set.add(arr[i]);
}
```

I think that it is *O(n)*, but I'm not sure since it is using `Set` and this contains methods as well. It is also calling the `add` method of `set`.

Can anyone confirm and explain what the time complexity of the entire above code is? Also, how much space would it take?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

i believe its O(n) because you loop over the array, and `contains` and `add` should be constant time because its a *hash* based set.  If it were not hash based and required iteration over the entire set to do lookups, the upper bound would be n^2.

Integers are immutable, so the space complexity would be 2n, which I believe simplifies to just n, since constants don't matter.

If you had objects in the array and set, then you would have 2n references and n objects, so you are at 3n, which is still linear (times a constant) space constraints.

EDIT-- yep "This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets."

see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Understanding `HashSet` is the key of question

According to `HashSet` in Javadoc,

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
> (actually a HashMap instance)...This class offers constant time
> performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size)

A more complete explain about `HashSet` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-contains-method-in-java/?ref=rp

So the `HashSet` `insert` and `contains` are `O(1)`.  ( As `HashSet` is based on `HashMap` and Its memory complexity is `O(n)`)

The rest is simple, the main array you are looping is order of `O(n)` , so the total order of function will be `O(n)`.